# HOW TO create a custom xml-tag so that all contents are CDATA-like to be used XML&XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags, cdata

I am trying to create a simple and clean XML structure with code for multiple languages, as this is supported by browsers. By using XSLT it would convert into HTML.

Since there is coding inside each TAGs contents, I have to use CDATA structure. Which works like `<PRE><CODE>` or the old `<XMP>` in  HTML.

However, I see redundant to embed a tag into another, and I would like the end results to be cleaner.

**The question is if I can make INTRO and CODE tags to act as CDATA, or CDATA to be named as the TAGs.**

Note: The intro-tag is just a markdown language.

[image: example, including some '<' and '>']

#### just example

```
<codechunk>

<intro><![CDATA[
# Hello world example in multiple languages
Lorem Ipsum

Hola mundo

- comentarios
- list something
- if...else
]]></intro>

<CODE lang="r"><![CDATA[
inline_func <- `(x) x+x;
`%+%` <- function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep="")
]]></CODE>

<CODE lang="lua"><![CDATA[
local read, write = io.read, io.write
local num, nl = '*n', '\n'
while 1 < 2  do
    local a = read(num)
    if a >= 42 then return end
    write(a, nl)
end
]]></CODE>

<CODE lang="python"><![CDATA[
inline_func = lambda x: return ln(x) < log(x);
]]></CODE>

</codechunk>
```

Comment: I don't see any characters used that would require escaping or use of a CDATA section. You would need it to e.g. not need to escape HTML or XML markup. But your current samples don't have any characters that appear to need to be put into a CDATA section to be not interpreted as markup by an XML parser.

Comment: You are right! Sorry for missing this. But I understand that '<' and '<' are common things in coding.. I just quickly added some to the same code.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what are you asking. CDATA is not a "tag". If you want your XML to contain text that may contain reserved characters then you must either escape the characters or put the text inside a CDATA section. There is no magical element that would automatically act as a CDATA wrapper for it contents. Although when you're doing an XSL transformation you can designate certain XML elements as elements whose text node children should be output using CDATA sections, the texts you pass to these elements must either be already escaped or come from CDATA sections in the original.

Comment: Sorry to make you struggle, I wasn't looking about magic, rather searching for meta-tag to define the behavior of a certain tag contents or just rename the CDATA as CODE in be able to use it from XSLT. Both ways (if at all possible) wouldn't required a third server-side language. I assume that the browser is not limited but probably the standard is.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the terms you are using. I don't know what you mean by "meta tag" or "rename the CDATA as CODE". I suggest you formulate your question in terms of input, process and desired output. You have tagged this as  `xslt` but I don't see where a transformation would be required or helpful. If by chance you want the XSLT processor to automatically recognize CDATA sections in the source and do something about them, that's not possible.  The transformation operates on the parsed tree, and the processor does not know if the source text was wrapped in CDATA section or escaped

Comment: For what it's worth, at https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea the HTML tag soup `<pre><code data-lang=python>inline_func = lambda x: return ln(x) < log(x);</code></pre>` doesn't validate, instead gives the error "Bad character `  ` after `<`. Probable cause: Unescaped `<`. Try escaping it as `&lt;`". So even with HTML your code samples trying to use `<` would need escaping. So with XML you have the choice the escape the characters like `<` and `&` requiring that or to use a CDATA section wrapper. But there is no way to declare an element/tag like `xmp` from previous HTML versions.

Comment: In terms of XSLT, I don't see how the question matters, as has already been pointed out, the XSLT processor operates on a tree model (usually created by an underlying XML parser) and has plain text nodes with (Unicode) characters, whether you use `<code>a &lt; b</code> or `<code><![CDATA[a < b]]></code>`.

Comment: Then the question is answered as not-possible. "HOW TO create a custom xml-tag so that all contents are CDATA-like?" It can't. Also you mention escaping in the example, but I don't have that issue. I was just trying to find alternate methods to have this codes simple and clean. I will find another way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. If you want to have special characters like `<` and `&` in text or attribute content in an XML document, they either have to be escaped as `&lt;` or `&amp;`, or they have to be in CDATA sections.

There are other solutions, of course, but they aren't XML.

You could use JSON, but that would only move the problem: instead of escaping `<` and `&`, you would have to escape `"` and `\`.

You could use SGML which would allow you to change the special characters to ones of your own choice, but then you severely restrict your choice of tools; or you could define your own proprietary format to your own design in which case you would have to write all your own tools.

It's one of those problems where the easiest thing is to live with it.